# Without Class and inherted, is there a method to do the owner drawing of a button/combobox/listbox/listview control?

Tags: c, windows

According MSDN,WM_DRAWITEM is a useful message to do owner drawing of some contorls. While you should hanlde the parent message procedure of WM_DRAWITEM. If you want to write some features for a control, you should both rewrite the control's window procedure and the parent holder's procedure.
So the owner drawing program structure like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ParentProc(HWND hwnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message){
    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT: {
        //ctrl background.
    } break;
    case WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX:{
        //ctrl background.
    } break;
    // and other controls.    
    case WM_DRAWITEM:  {
            LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT draw_struct = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
            
            if(draw_struct->CtlType == ODT_BUTTON) {
                //Button owner drawing
            }
            else if(draw_struct->CtlType == ODT_STATIC) {
                //static ctrl owner drawing
            }
            else if(draw_struct->CtlType == ODT_LISTBOX) {
                //Listbox owner drawing
            }
            else if(draw_struct->CtlType == ODT_COMBOBOX) {
                //ComboBox owner drawing
            }
            else if(draw_struct->CtlType == ODT_LISTVIEW) {
                //ListView owner drawing
            }
            else if(draw_struct->CtlType == ODT_MENU) {
                //Menu item owner drawing
            }
            // and so on.
        }
    break;
    //......
}
```

If you want your rewriting was useful on somewhere else, you seemed have to do the same. The subclass of the controls are very indepent, howerver , if you want your code works , you should also modify the procedure of the parent window , that looks not very well , compared with C++ controls (such as mfc), which the class of control does the whole job. It seems more convient,complete, no need to deal with the parent window. With inherit method, OOP can easily do this in there window classes structure. C++ controls have the top level design for message reflection. They have good encapsulation.

I want the code more concentrated in the control. When I want to do something with the control , code happened more in the control itself, no refer to its parent window. Also when I do the coding, I hope what I have done with the control colud be reused somewhere else. Yes, like the c++ controls , I want encapsulation.
So there are some steps need to be done:

1. Handle the procedure of the control's parent window,capture the message related to the control.
2. When parent window recive the WM_DRAWITEM,reflect the messsage to the control.
3. subclassing the control window procedure , handle the messsage send from the parent window.
   I'm trying like this:

```
//the user-defined message for relection.
#define WM_BTNCUSTOMDRAW (UINT)(WM_USER+0x0001)

HWND parent;
HWND button;

LRESULT CALLBACK ParentProc(HWND hwnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) {
//part of control's parent window procedure
    case WM_DRAWITEM:
        {
            LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT draw_struct = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
            
            if(draw_struct->CtlType == ODT_BUTTON) {
                return SendMessage(draw_struct->hwndItem,WM_BTNCUSTOMDRAW,wParam,lParam);
            }
            //...

        }
    break;
    //...
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MyButtonProc(HWND hwnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) {
//part of control's window procedure
case WM_BTNCUSTOMDRAW: {
    //...
} break;
...
}

//modify the window procedure.
SetWindowLongPtr(parent,GWLP_WNDPROC,(LONG_PTR)ParentProc);
SetWindowLongPtr(button,GWLP_WNDPROC,(LONG_PTR)MyButtonProc);
```

The function of MyButtonProc is necessary. The modification of the parent window seemed very wired. If there are hundred of sub controls, the parent window procedure would be a mess.
Is it possible to finish the encapsulation with only C grammar?

Hoping for your excellent coding skills.

Comment: GUI apps without an OO language is just ghastly, and this is a major reason why:(

Comment: I'm waiting for some some coding skills , I believe there would a simple easy way.

Comment: Well, I wish you all the best, but fear the worst:)

Comment: It's interesting , don't you think ? The grammar does not forbid anything,  In fact , C grammar looks more flexible. why so hard?

Comment: why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I'm really trying doing this, C code is really more simple, easy to read, class have to many wrappers.

Comment: Why would it be a mess? You have to handle only a fixed number of control types - ODT_BUTTON, ODT_STATIC etc. Microsoft documents only 7 types.

Comment: There are only sereval owner drawing controls supported , by this what you said is corrent.However, You should consider the including and nested situations , for example : main panel( sub panel ( sub panel_for_next_level (....((..controlA),controlB)....)controln).... you will have to handle all the panels's message WM_DRAWITEM. That's a disaster.